# How to handle new tab in cypress .If sub domain is dynamic?

Tags: cypress

URL:-   https://localhost:8008/

Sub domain URL:  https://localhost:8008/datasearch?actionId=772675

I am not able handle new tab in cypress as cy.visit('https://localhost:8008/datasearch?actionId=772675')  as action id keeps on changing after entering data and click on submit button.As subdomain opens on new tab.I need to check the assert the output that is opening in new tab.

Regards

Kushal

Comment: ..Can you please add test code till you click on the link/tab/menu which open a new tab.

Comment: After entering data in form.I am trying to click on submit button cy.get('.mt-2 > .btn-primary').click()  1. After clicking on submit new tab will open 2. New tab url is dynamic

Comment: Can you please post the `html` tag of the button please, does the submit tag look like this `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button>Click me !</button></a>`

Answer (score 1):

I assume in your case if your submit button is inside an 'a' tag, then you could do something like this. If you click the Submit button, then it will open as a new tab, so ideally you should be getting the link from the 'a' tag or submit button prior to click and pass to a `const` and use `cy.visit()`

```
context('Open as new tab in cypress', () => {
        it('Test to open a new tab/subdomain in cypress', () => {
          cy.visit('https://localhost:8008/');
          cy.get('.mt-2 > .btn-primary').then(($ele)=>{   // if the button is in an '<a>' tag, you could grab something like this
            const newUrl =  Cypress.$($ele).attr('href'); 
            cy.visit(newUrl);
          })
        })
    })
```

Comment: How to this when <a> tag does not have href attribute in it.  I have button like this, on clicking it, a new tab opens up.                                          <a class="btn primary alignedBtn submitButton">SubmitTest</a>